# fail2ban and owncloud.log file

Tags: owncloud, fail2ban

I am using the following configuration, ubuntu 16.04 apache2 php 7.0 owncloud 10.0.3.  I think I have made an error when I setup ownclound.  The data directory lives in /var/www/owncloud/data ( I believe that owncloud.log resides in this folder).  I have deployed fail2ban and the issue that I am having is that fail2ban cannot access the data folder because I ran sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/owncloud/.  The only way I access the log file is through the OWNcloud gui settings > general > log. where I can see the failed login attempts by me.  I cannot seem to get Fail2ban to read the owncloud log.

I am new to ubuntu and Owncloud can anyone advise how to rectify this issue, owncloud is working fine and I am using ip addresses to restrict access to owncloud. Fail2ban was supposed to make the server secure so that I could open up owncloud to the internet.

Regards

Steve

Answer (score 0):

You should change the permissions of the log file so that it can be read by everyone but written only by the php process. Do a 'chmod 755 /var/log/owncloud/owncloud.log'
By the way. I suggest that you migrate from Owncloud to Nextcloud. It is a full replacement, fully open source, more features and more secure. And it has a fail2ban equivalent brute force protection already build in :-)